# Segue don't present view on iOS7

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7, segue

I have noticed an odd behavior on iOS 7.x, basically I have a "navigation controller" that has set the Home of my app as "rootview controller".

Also, I have another view that allows to select a database through "uitableview". After that, the Home will start the download of the database.

When the app launches, the first thing it does is showing the page of the database selection. After that, in the different views of the app, there are buttons that allow to deselect a database.

The problem is that this works great on iOS 6.x, while it doesn't on iOS 7.x
I'll list below the code I use for this, with the opportune comments.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ( [bridge needJump] ) {//controllo il flag per forzare il salto alla schermata di scelta del db
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goSelDB" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview:hud];
        hud.delegate = self;

        if ([bridge firsStart])//controllo il flag del primo avvio
        {
            if([bridge checkNetwork])//
            {
                [self downloadDbWithUrl:[bridge getDBUrl] andDestinationName:@"ristorante.sqlite"];
            }
            else
            {
                [self fillField];

                UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Errore:" message:@"Per usare questa applicazione devi essere connesso a internet." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [al show];
            }
            [bridge setFirst:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [self fillField];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Present viewController (Perform segue) after its presenting viewController view has been appeared . Do all the stuff in **viewDidAppear:** method.